# Creating a search field in Slim

Tags: php, slim

I'm sure this is going to be a stupid question because it seems so obvious, but I have spent way too long looking for an answer.  I'm using Slim 2.6, eloquent and twig and I'm a bit rusty.

I'm working on an existing, but still pretty basic inventory management system for chemicals at the University I work at and just want to add the search function.  I have the route itself working, so if I type append to the url /find/mySearchTerm it works exactly as expected, but I cannot figure out how to pass/pull the search term into the route.

This is my route, which works fine manually:

```
$app->get('/find/:searchterm', function($searchterm) use ($app) {
    $chemicals = $app
         ->chemical
         ->where('item', 'LIKE', "%$searchterm%")
         ->orWhere('catalogue', 'LIKE', "%$searchterm%")
         ->get();
});
```

I could use javascript or DOM or something to pull the text of the field and add it in, but that just does not seem like...the slim / eloquent / twig way.

```
<form method='post' action ="{{ urlFor('search', { searchterm: searchterm } ) }}">
    Search: <input type='text' name='searchterm' />
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Hopefully I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://gordonlesti.com/creating-a-search-in-slim-framework-with-hooks/  and not this    http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/

Comment: Hooks, of course. You're exactly right, that 2nd link is quite old and very un-Slim like.
I think this is what I needed. Thanks very much zod

Comment: @zod On second thought, even hooks were more than I needed to use in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally achieved what I was trying to do, and I was definitely overthinking things. I added the home post route and called that from the form submittal, instead of 'search' directly and passed in the search term retrieved from the post request.  Search route is same as above

```
<form method='post' action ="{{ urlFor('home.search' ) }}">
```

My Post method

```
$app->post('/', function() use ($app) { 
$request = $app->request;   
$searchterm = $request->post('searchterm');

$app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('search', [
    'searchterm' => $searchterm 
 ]));

})->name('home.search');
```